# Running Amazon EventBridge locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I am currently developing a system to be deployed on AWS. A collection of services that communicate using events delivered through Amazon EventBridge. I'm struggling to find a way to run my system locally because I don't know how I can either

1. Run a local version of EventBridge (docker or something)
2. Get the EventBridge instance on AWS to send events to my local machine (I'm assuming this is impossible?).

Is there a way I can run my services locally, have a service send an event to a real (or mocked) EventBridge instance and have those events routed to my local services?

Not that its too important, but my services are .NET Core applications running on Windows.

Comment: I suggest looking at LocalStack https://github.com/localstack/localstack

Comment: A roundabout solution would be introduce us eventbridge schema to create a valid event and then use it in your local testing.

Answer (score 26):

[LocalStack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) can run on your local machine and has support for the EventBridge API.

Comment: I wish I could give both the question and answer 5 stars for the amount of searching it took me to find this.